# How to save html table as an image for client to save on their computer

Tags: javascript, php, save, screenshot

I have a website which generates a table (using php echoes out a table) from some lines a user pastes into a text area. I would like my clients be able to save this table on their machine. This is what I have found so far http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ but don't know how to use it.  Also sometime in the future I would like it to have a "share on facebook" button so that the image is uploaded to their facebook account.

I have searched Google for 2 days now without any result all ones I could find like php function saved the image to the server instead of the clients machine. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be an image?  Would generating a PDF on the fly suffice?

Comment: has to be image to be posted on facebook later on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use canvas for that. Simply put all you data in canvas and you will get the output as image. A better example can be [found here](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-convert-canvas-data-image)

```
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
table
{
border=5;
}
</style>
<p><canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
               "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px'>" +
                 "<table><tr><td>HI</td><td>Welcome</td></tr><tr><td>Hello</td><td>World</td></tr> </table>" +
               "</div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
img.src = url;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks looks exactly like what i need. But I cant figure out how to put my table into a canvas, when i do canvas remains blank

Comment: inside canvas add a <div> tag and enter your table there. then close the div tag before closing the canvas tag

Comment: <canvas><div><table> etc... </table></div></canvas>
only a blank rectangle appears

Comment: i would like you to view http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-canvas-text.php and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas as this might be helpful

Comment: If you just stick the HTML directly inside the canvas element, then it treats it as [fallback content (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_usage#Fallback_content)

Comment: is there any way other than editing every line? because my site is 1000+ lines of code for the table

Comment: perhaps you can experiment with iframe. Take the table inside iframe and use iframe inside canvas

Answer (score 0):

Use `PHP GD` to create images on the go.

Using this will return a header type `Content-type: image/png` when the php file is called. (Note: You cannot return html along with the image in this php, since we define the header type to image/png)

Alternatively you can generate pdf files which support tables. A best library to generate pdf's is `FPDF`
See the table generation example in fpdf [**here**](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm)

Links:

[PHP GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

[FPDF](http://fpdf.org)

Comment: Outputting images is trivial... getting HTML rendered is the tricky part, and I'm afraid you don't answer that question.

Comment: It needs to be an image file because can't post PDFS on facebook.
Also I couldn't find anything to make a table in PHP GD thanks for the prompt answer though

Comment: @brad I agree with what you said. The tricky part is writing the code for table in the image. But it is definitely possible through GD. For example, take the calendar app on facebook..They grab images of users and layer it over the base image. Similarly @ philip should probably use layering in order to achieve the result but again its restricted.

Comment: @SaiSasidhar, Of course you can create any raster graphic with GD, but that's not what he wants to do.  He wants to render the HTML.  That cannot be done with GD alone.